# Every 5th child with nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to apply a style to every 5th li, including the first li.

I have tried:

```
nth-child(1n+5)
```

But this does not apply it to the first child. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other way around; you’re looking for `:nth-child(5n+1)`.

The first number is the multiplier (in this case every 5th item) and the second number the offset. The offset is 1 because you want to start at the first item - if you left it off it’d start on the 0th and then show on the 5th.

Answer (score 5):

You can select every 5th element with `nth-child(5n+5)` and then also select first `li` with `li:nth-child(1)` or `li:first-child`

```css
li:nth-child(5n+5), li:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It never fails to get a chuckle out of me whenever I see someone using `ul { list-style-type: decimal }` as if there's no way to mark up an ordered list in HTML ;)

Answer (score 1):

Variation on what Nenad has posted. Essentially, however, you can't combine what you want to do with a single `nth` declaration. If you find yourself fighting with this sort of thing a lot, http://nth-calculator.com/ and http://nth-test.com/ may help you out :)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: decimal
}

li:first-child, li:nth-child(5n) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the http://nth-test.com/ link. Great resource tool. Cheers!